# How to Generate a PDF using NodeJs, EJS and Mysql data

Tags: mysql, node.js, pdf, ejs

I want  to Show My MYSQL data on using nodejs on my ejs PDF
So i  Had a problem to show up the data on the PDF format  :
This is My node js code Where i want to send data(MYSQL database) from JS to EJS file and show it in pdf format:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
pdf = require('express-pdf');
const ejs =  require('ejs');
//Connection to database
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit :10,
    host :"localhost" ,
    user :"root",
    password :"",
    database :"backend",
    multipleStatements: true

})
module.exports={
//Creation Of pdf
    pdfversion : function(req,res){
        res.pdfFromHTML({
           filename: 'templatee.ejs',
           html: path.resolve(__dirname, './templatee.ejs')
           
           });  
     },
//Getting the data from MYSQL database
     getonetva : function(req , res){
        pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{
            if(err) throw err        
            const id = req.params.id;
            const data =`SELECT *  FROM formulaire ` ;
            connection.query(data, (err,rows) =>{
                 connection.release()
                 console.log(rows)
                 if(!err){
                     res.send(rows)

//res.render To send the data to EJS file , and i think i have the Problem here :
                     res.render('./templatee.ejs', {
                        results: JSON.stringify(rows)
                    });
                 console.log(rows);
                 }
                 else{
                     console.log(err)
                 }
    
            })
        } )
     
    },
```

And we have the EJS file :

```
<div class="table-data">
    <h2>Display Data Node.js & MySQL</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>            
                <th> Name</th>
                <th>Last Name </th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone number</th>   
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td><%=results.nom %></td>
                <td><%=results.prenom %></td>
                <td><%=results.email %></td>
                <td><%=results.tel %></td>          
            </tr>           
        </table>
        </div>
```

and Router :

```
const fac = require('../Controller/gestclient');
const route = require('express').Router();
route.get('/topdf',fac.pdfversion);
route.get('/show',fac.getalltva);
module.exports = route
```

And this is the Result that i get when i type http://localhost:5000/gestion/topdf : It shows the template, but without substitutions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to render your ejs template before you hand it off to `.pdfFromHTML()`. Try something like this, using a [callback in your invocation of `res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render).

This isn't debugged.

```js
pdfversion : function(req,res, next){
  /* get your data from SELECT */
  res.render(
    './templatee.ejs', 
    { results: JSON.stringify(rows) },
      function (err, html) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        res.pdfFromHTML( {
          htmlContent: html,
          directory: '/tmp' })
       } )
     }
   )
}
```

Comment: I get this problem (Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client) and thank u for the Answer